# how to display embedded manifest

Tags: visual-c++, wix

I have some projects built with different versions of VS2005 that require different run-time version. i need to display the assemblyIdentity to see which run-time is required to run the program. I need the information to include the specific VC80 runtime MSM in my WiX installer project.

*{Edit}*
While the binaries have been built with Visual Studio I don't have a VS on the PCs where WiX shall be used. I am reluctant to install an Express version, since I am a guest on that PC.
*{/Edit}*

How can I conviniently display the embedded manifest? Preferrable with a small tool, command line tool would be OK.

Comment: If the binaries depend on different versions of VC runtime, you have to include only the highest of them and include the corresponding *policy*.msm. The latter instructs the system to redirect dependencies on lower version to the latest version installed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [PeStudio](http://www.winitor.net/de/pestudio.html) is a small tool that does the job. Including displaying the manifest in clear text.

Additionally it displays all DLLs that must be present on target system. That helps to author the installer.

Answer (score 0):

Manifests are stored as resource in executables/DLLs. These are stored under `RT_MANIFEST`resource type. Open the resources under it and parse it as XML.

One example is pasted below (I opened one of my EXE using VS resource editor):

[image: Example]

Comment: I have tested this with VS2008. This shows me the manifest as a hex dump. With the ASCII column I can also see the text, but this isn't better than loading the DLL in notepad.

Comment: Read the stuff as normal text and parse as XML. You need to use `FindResource`, `LoadResource` and `LockResource` to read the given resource.

Comment: So there if no convenient way. I will have to write my own program.probably opening with notepad is a appropriate solution.

Comment: @harper I open .exe and .dll with Far and search `manifest`. If Far is not available, Notepad does this job, yet not very convenient.